# Please help to show a function is unbounded and thus not Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering how I can show the following function is not Riemann integrable.

Since we are on a closed and bounded interval I couldn't use that it is unbounded, etc (think)

$$g(x)=2x\cos\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})}{x}$$ if $x \neq 0$, $0$ if $x=0$ considered on [-1,1]

How could I show it is not Riemann integrable?

I was given the suggestion in the comments to consider $$x_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1/2)(\pi)}}$$

When I consider the hint and plug in I get
$$2\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1/2)\pi}}\cos\frac{1}{(2n+1/2)\pi}+2\sin\frac{1}{(2n+1/2)\pi} {\sqrt{(2n+1/2)\pi}}$$
However, I still cant figure out how I can use this to show it is not bounded. Can someone please shed light on this part?
But I am not making progress on how this can be used to prove it is not Riemann integrable

Comment: It seems like $g$ blows up near $0$

Comment: A necessary condition for Riemann integrability is to be bounded

Comment: So It isnt bouned on [-1,1] , would I show this by limit

Comment: @Quality Just evaluate at $x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{(2n+\frac12)\pi}}$

Comment: So what do think the problem is?

Comment: @FoobazJohn  hmm thanks, does it matter that it is defined as 0 at x=0 though?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Thank you for suggestion. But what should I do with this? For example, when n=1 I evaluate it to be $sqrt(10\pi)$, when n=2, $3 \sqrt(2\pi)$ etc

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Would it show that G is unbounded on the interval?

Comment: @Quality By taking a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $0$ such that $1/x_n^2$ is, say, $\pi/2$ plus an integer multiple of $\pi$, you can prove that $g$ is not bounded and therefore not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, could you possible elaborate more on this? It seems that in the answers some users say I cannot do it this way

Comment: @Ian  Please let me know if you get the chance

Comment: @Quality I said what there is to say in my comment on the answer: unbounded functions are never properly Riemann integrable, and it is not hard to see that this function is not bounded.

Comment: @Ian  Thanks, sorry I didnt see that

Comment: The " cosine term" in $g(x)$ never exceeds $|2 x|$ in absolute value. So for $x$ approaching $0$ the value of  $g(x)$ is dominated by the "sine term" .

Comment: @user254665  Thank you. I still dont understand though. I am so confused. For x approaching zero yes, but how does this tie in with the sequence given in the hint?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have tried to update my answer. I am trying for hours to use your hint to show it is unbounded. I am not making any progress. Can you please explain it a bit more if possible

Comment: Your evaluation of the second term of $g(x_n)$ in the Q is erroneous. In the Q, $g(x_n)=2(-1)^n /x_n=(-1)^n\sqrt {(2 n+1/2)\pi}.$

Comment: Actually your evaluation of the first term of  $g(x_n)$ in the Q is erroneous also. You've got some values "upside-down."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every nbhd of $0$ there is a strictly decreasing positive sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ with $\sin 1/x_{2 n}^2=1$ and  $\sin 1/x_{2 n-1}^2=-1.$ Since  $2 x_n \cos (1/x_n^2)=0$  we have $$g(x_{2 n})=2/x_{2 n}\; \text { and }\; g(x_{2 n-1}=-2/x_{2 n-1}.$$ The variation in $g$ in any nbhd of $0$ is therefore at least $$\sup_{m\in N} \sum_{n=1}^m |f(x_{2 n-1})-f(x_{2 n})|=\sup_{m\in N}\sum_{n=1}^k(2/x_{2 n-1}+2/x_{2 n})\geq \sup_{m\in N}2/x_{2 m}=\infty.$$ Remark:  The term  $2 x \cos 1/x^2$ is bounded in absolute value by $2$ for $x\ne 0$, so if it were replaced by any term bounded (in absolute value) by some $k>0$ we would have $|f(x_{2 m-1})-f(x_{2 m})|\geq 2/ x_{2 m-1}+2/x_{2 m}-2 k >2/x_{2m}-2 k,$ which goes to $\infty$ as $m\to \infty.$